# Excel conditional formatting not copy

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am working on an excel spreadsheet where i'm trying to set up conditional formatting.

I have set this up using the formula =$i4="Outstanding" and the range to update is "$A$2:$E$2".
This works absolutely fine however I have 50 other rows that this needs to be applied to and it doesn't work when I copy/past etc.

Right now, I can't get it to work, I've tried copy and paste, dragging down from the corner of the cell and format painter.

When I do this, it carries over the above range("$A$2:$E$2") instead of updating to "$A$3:$E$3".

Whilst I appreciate that the cell is 'Absolute' and not 'Relative', I am unable to update this or find a solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do all the rows look at `I4` or will it need to iterate to `I5`, `I6`, etc?

Comment: It will need to iterate, essentially it's an action tracker and each row will have the I3, I4, i5 etc updated and i need to row to highlight in red/green etc

Comment: Then just change the applies to to `=$A$2:$E$52`  not need for copy paste  One rule will work for them all. as long as in your formula the row is relative: `=$I4="Outstanding"` then Excel will iterate the row respectively on its own.

Comment: Wow, it was that easy
Thank you!